# SQL statement to find values close to each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm struggling with defining the SQL to find a list of values that are statistically close to each other. For example, let's say we have a table of prices, and I want to get all the prices that vary within $0.25 of each other.

**Prices:
1.00
1.25
2.00
4.00
4.50
4.75
5.00**

For the example above, this should return 1.00, 1.25, 4.50, 4.75, and 5.00 as they are within 0.25 of another value in the list.

I don't want to get a raw list and then process it in the code. It would be much more efficient for SQL server to do the work. Is this possible?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? That may affect the bets answer. Also, it isn't necessary the case that SQL is more efficient for this sort of processing than loading  the list and processing.

Comment: This is for SQL Server v11.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might use a correlated subquery:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (val DECIMAL (9,2))
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (1),(1.25),(2),(4),(4.5),(4.75),(5)

SELECT * 
  FROM @tbl a 
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                FROM @tbl b 
               WHERE     b.val <> a.val 
                     AND b.val BETWEEN a.val-.25 AND a.val+.25)
```

You could also work an ABS into this which might be more succinct but probably doesn't impact performance:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM @tbl a 
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                FROM @tbl b 
               WHERE     b.val <> a.val 
                     AND ABS(b.val - a.val) <= .25)
```

EDIT: I switch from Float to Decimal, because that's a "better" type in SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you Karl. This is exactly what I was looking for. When I have multiple values in the table e.g. 1, 1.25, 1.25, 2, 4, 4.5, 4.75, 5, the result was 1, 1.25, 1.25, 4.5, 4.75, 5. Perfect!

Answer (score 5):

Try a join of the table with itself:

```
declare @Values table (value float)
insert into @Values values (1),(1.25),(2),(4),(4.5),(4.75),(5)

select distinct A.Value
from @values A
inner join @Values B
    on abs(A.value - B.Value) <= 0.25
    and A.Value <> B.Value
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/479)

OR in another approach, using `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN N.n=1 THEN A.Value ELSE ant END
FROM @Values A
cross apply (select max(value) from @Values where Value < A.Value) B(ant)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2)N(n)
where abs(A.value - ant) <= 0.25
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/480)

And, if you are using SQL Server 2012+, you can use [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh213125.aspx) function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN N.n=1 THEN A.Value ELSE ant END
FROM (
    SELECT Value, 
        LEAD(Value, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY Value) AS Ant
    FROM @Values
) A
CROSS APPLY(SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2)N(n)
where abs(Ant - Value) <= 0.25
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/117)

Comment: Thanks Nizam. This seems promising, however, it limits the list to distinct values. In my case I need all the values that are close to each other.

Comment: You can use a subquery, like `SELECT * FROM @VALUES WHERE VALUE IN ( --- one of the suggested solutions --- )`. Please, look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/482.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (Nums float)

insert into @TBL values (1),(1.25),(2),(4),(4.5),(4.75),(5);

WITH CTE AS(
Select  t1.Nums as T1,t2.Nums as T2 From @TBL t1
CROSS JOIN @TBL t2)
Select  distinct ct.T1 From CTE ct
where abs(ct.T1 - ct.T2) = 0.25
order by ct.T1
```